# Optimal segment size for store-and-forward switching

Tags: switching, latency

Suppose we are transmitting a file of size `X` *bits* from `A` to `B`. They are connected to each other with a single switch using store-and-forward switching. Before transmission, `A` splits the file into segments of size `L` and adds *80 bits* for  header data. The links between `A`, `B` and the switch have a maximum throughput of `R` *bps*.

**How would I got about finding an optimal value for `L` so that latency between `A` and `B` is minimal?**

I know that the number of packets is `X/L` and the size of a packet being transmitted is `80 + L`, which results in a single packet latency from `A` to `B` of `2*(L+80/R)`.

Comment: Sorry, all *certification, educational and homework* questions are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Alright. Sorry, I didn't know.